# How to build multiple docker containers from jenkinsfile?

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile, devops

I have 3 different Docker images. I need to build these images from Jenkins file. I have Wildfly, Postgres, Virtuoso Docker images with individual Docker file. As of now, I am using the below command to build these images:

The directory structure is, Docker is the root diretory.

Docker->build->1. wildfly 2. postgres 3. virtuoso

In my jenkins file I have below command to build the image:

```
stage('Building test images')
{
   sh 'docker build -t virtuoso -f $WORKSPACE/build/virtuoso/Dockerfile .'
}
```

But I am getting error as below:

```
Step 7/16 : COPY ./install $VIRT_HOME/install
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder636357036/install: no such file or directory
[Pipeline] }
```

For reference below is my dockerfile:

```
FROM virtuoso:latest

ENV var1 /opt/virtuoso-opensource
ENV VIRT_db /opt/virtuoso-opensource/var/lib/virtuoso/db
ENV RUN_CONFIG=/opt/virtuoso-opensource/install/config

RUN export PATH=$PATH:/opt/virtuoso-opensource/bin

RUN mkdir $var1/install

COPY ./install $var1/install

WORKDIR $VIRT_db
CMD ["/opt/virtuoso-opensource/bin/init.sh"]
```

And the workspace is /home/jenkins/Docker and my guess  is I am running docker build command from $workspace directory and this command should run from the virtuoso directory.

My question is how build image from Jenkins file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the easiest solution to solve this would be to enter the proper folder in the script before executing the `docker build` command. 
e.g.:

```
stage('Building test images') {
  steps {
    sh '''
      cd $WORKSPACE/build/virtuoso
      docker build -t virtuoso .
    ''' 
  }
}
```

Comment: @Shanmukh please consider to accept the answer if it helped !

Comment: @LinPy ..... I consider to accept only those answers which works for me. Not every answer as comment.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the answer:

```
stage('Build images'){
    echo "workspace directory is ${workspace}"
    dir ("$workspace/build/virtuoso")
    {
        sh 'docker build -t virtuoso -f $WORKSPACE/build/virtuoso/Dockerfile .'
    }
    dir ("$workspace/build/wildfly")
    {
        sh 'docker build -t wildfly -f $WORKSPACE/build/wildfly/Dockerfile .'
    }
    dir ("$workspace/build/postgres")
    {
        sh 'docker build -t postgres -f $WORKSPACE/build/postgres/Dockerfile .'
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping me out.